# Foreach loop container SSIS

Tags: foreach, ssis, ssis-2012, foreach-loop-container

I have a Foreachloop Container in my SSIS package under which a File system task is placed which moves files from Source Folder to the Destination folder and with that container, some other tasks are further connected.

Every time I run the package, all task starts running one by one despite having any new file in Source folder which always takes time.

Is there any way that if a new file added in Source folder then only all task
run and if there is no file then only container run and package gets fail and show the message of No new file found through Script task?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the names of the files that were loaded in a table and then use a script task to check if the files in the folder are present in that table and if any new file is found then execute the entire process

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron but I don't have too much knowledge in programming to code the script task. My intention is that could it be possible through the Precedence constraint with some expressions?

Comment: Alternatively you could check [this](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2015/04/how-to-reject-already-loaded-files-and.html) out. It does the same thing without using Script tasks

Comment: yeah that link is pretty much useful, But I was thinking that if we could count the looping files and make some Expression in Precedence Constraint like if Count is 0 then constraint doesn't pass the connection to the next task. something like that.

Comment: when you say count is 0 do you mean you will be moving the loaded files to another folder?

Comment: No. what I am thinking is that suppose we have 5 files in our source folder, then by somehow we save this number in a variable and make the procedence constraint (Constraint and Expression) like @Count > 0 then Success otherwise Fail. This is what i think.

Comment: trying but not getting result.. Any way thanks for support :)